Induced homomorphism of Abel-Jacobi map is surjective for genus 1
I'm trying to prove that every Riemann surface of genus 1 is biholomorphic to a torus, via a sequence of exercises in Richard Hain's lecture 'Moduli of Riemann surfaces, transcendental aspects'. He starts as follows:
Let $X$ be a compact connected Riemann surface of genus 1, let $\omega$ be a non-zero holomorphic 1-form on $X$, and let $\Lambda = \{\int_a\omega \; \colon a \text{ is a  loop in }X\}$.

Prove $\Lambda$ is a lattice.

Let $x_0\in X$ and define the function $\nu \colon X \to \mathbb{C}/\Lambda$, $\nu(x) = \int_\gamma \omega$ where $\gamma$ is a path form $x_0$ to $x$. Show that $\nu$ is a well-defined holomorphic covering map, and induces a surjective homomorphism of fundamental groups $\nu_* \colon \pi_1(X,x_0) \to \pi_1(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda,0) \cong \Lambda$.

Conclude that $\nu$ is a biholomorphism.


So far I've been able to prove part 1 and that $\nu$ is a well-defined holomorphic covering map, and that $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda,0) \cong \Lambda$. I also know that $\nu$ being a covering map implies that $\nu_*$ is injective. However, I can't manage to prove that $\nu_*$ is surjective. I also don't understand the relevance of the isomorphism $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda,0) \cong \Lambda$.
My thoughts on proving the surjectivity are:
Let $[f]\in \pi_1(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda,0)$ and $f$ a path in $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$. Then there is a unique lifting of $f$, say $\tilde f$ that starts in $x_0$ and such that $\nu\circ\tilde f = f$. I also know that $\nu\circ\tilde f(1) \equiv 0$ in $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$, so $\tilde f(1) = \int_a\omega$ for some cylce $a$ in $X$. However, I want $\tilde f$ to be a loop at $x_0$, but if I try to prove $\tilde f(1) = x_0$ then I basically already prove injectivity of $\nu$, which would finish the proof anyhow since any holomorphic non constant map from a compact connected connected Riemann surface to a connected Riemann surface is surjective.
I've been stuck for quite some time now so I would appreciate any help you can offer.
